# Conversation - using entities values/size as a condition

Tags: ibm-watson, chatbot, watson-conversation

I'd like to know how to use the values from the entity as a **IF bot recognizes** 
 condition on Watson Conversation.

I have one menu for the users choose one option. And all of these options are inside one Entity called `@optionsNumbers` with the values: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`.

And I want to make one condition that will verify if user chooses more than one option.

**E.g:**

**Watson:** Hello, welcome to the Official Virtual Assistant from the Company XX. You can choose this options above: 
1. About products 2. About Services 3. Exit

**User:** I want the option 1 and 2

**So, the entity `@sys-number` have 2 values, and not just *one*, like I need.**

As you can see, the user types 2 values of the entity @option. And I'd like to know *how to recognize if the user typed more than one value for this particular entity*, also @sys-number, cause the user can type just **ONE option** (business rules).

I'm enthusiast about Watson and pretty sure I read all documentation. So, what I have tried and does not work (I saw these methods with Intents examples):

```
if bot recognizes entities.sys-number[1].value
if bot recognizes entities['sys-number'].size > 1
```

And I know that I can create two conditions, but if my Options menu have more than 20 options? That's why my asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you could use the system number entity built-in type provided by Watson :

`Entities > System Entities > Enable System Number`

Your intent should now be able to recognize it easily by default, let's check the following intent :

[image]

And you test it with the sandbox, it works as expected

[image]

---

**EDIT: Using Dialog to add a condition on sys-number**

Create new dialog node for matching the intent :

[image]

Then enable the `Multiple Responses` for this node ( click Customize ) :

[image]

Add your conditions as part of the responses  :

[image]

Then test your dialog :

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your help, upvote, but.. I'd like to use the **Entity option/sys-number** as a **condition**, using the *size* or values, not intents, cause if the user chooses more than one option, Watson will answer: Sorry, you can choose just one option! And I'm using the sys-number entity, the option entity is just one example that I used for asking